# Java Script code only Works for first Button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

im trying to implement a nav bar with buttons, which function as drop down lists. The event Listener is working but no matter which button I click it only opens the contents of the first one.

Here is my code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  const bnts = document.getElementsByClassName("dropbutton");
  bnts[i].addEventListener("click", showAndHide);

}

function showAndHide() {
  var click = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-content")[0];

  if (click.style.display === "none") {
    click.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    click.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="button1" class="dropbutton">Home</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button id="button1" class="dropbutton">Arrivals</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test111</a>
    <a href="#">Test222</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button id="button1" class="dropbutton">Clothing</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1123</a>
    <a href="#">Test212</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button id="button1" class="dropbutton">Schoes</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Testaasdf2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("drop-content")[0];` selects the first button element

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

```
function showAndHide(event){
   var click = event.target;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the same ID more than once. This is not allowed in HTML. IDs have to be unique. You are using `getElementsByClassName[0]`, which always returns the first element with that class. Since you `drop-content` always comes directly after the button, you can select the clicked button, then get the element after the button in the DOM by calling `nextElementSibling`.

Furthermore, you have set the loop to iterate 5 times while you only have 4 buttons, so it is always good practice to loop according to the number of buttons you have, by making the loop dependent on the number of buttons.

Actually you don't need IDs here, so I removed them. I re-wrote your code with the above notes in mind

```js
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropbutton");

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", showAndHide);

}

function showAndHide() {
  var click = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (click.style.display === "none") {
    click.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    click.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">Home</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropbutton">Arrivals</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test111</a>
    <a href="#">Test222</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropbutton">Clothing</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1123</a>
    <a href="#">Test212</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropbutton">Schoes</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Testaasdf2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the OP's default.

Answer (score 0):

1. delegate - then you do not need an ID on the button which has to be unique anyway
2. use a ternary or toggle the classList

```js
document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("dropbutton")) {
    tgt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show")
  }
})
```

```css
.drop-content {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">Home</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropbutton">Arrivals</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test111</a>
    <a href="#">Test222</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropbutton">Clothing</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1123</a>
    <a href="#">Test212</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropbutton">Schoes</button>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Testaasdf2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the content to be under the buttons and the buttons horizontally, use data attributes

```js
document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("dropbutton")) {
    const oldActive = document.querySelector("button.active");
    document.getElementById(oldActive.dataset.tgt).classList.toggle("show",0)
    document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.tgt).classList.toggle("show",1)
    oldActive.classList.toggle("active",0)
    tgt.classList.toggle("active",1)
  }
})
```

```css
.drop-content {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block
}

.active { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton active" data-tgt="home">Home</button>
  <button class="dropbutton" data-tgt="arrivals">Arrivals</button>
  <button class="dropbutton" data-tgt="clothing">Clothing</button>
  <button class="dropbutton" data-tgt="shoes">Schoes</button>

<div class="drop-content show" id="home">Home
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="drop-content" id="arrivals">Arrivals
    <a href="#">Test111</a>
    <a href="#">Test222</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="drop-content" id="clothing">Clothing
    <a href="#">Test1123</a>
    <a href="#">Test212</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="drop-content" id="shoes">Shoes
    <a href="#">Test1</a>
    <a href="#">Testaasdf2</a>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
const bnts = document.getElementsByClassName("dropbutton");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    bnts[i].addEventListener("click", showAndHide);
}
```

You should first to create the collection and only after to navigate inside it.